# How to reupdate all drivers after using Python script?

Tags: python, drivers

I need drivers and properties to be changed at the same time via my script. But the drivers are not updated after I press the "Run" button.
[image: struct]
After a property has been changed with a script, how do I force update all drivers?

**Edit:**
I completely forgot to mention that I have nested drivers.
Code `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` successfully updates everything, but nested drivers are updated with 80% success rate.

Comment: You sure have many many things in the script. :D 9 of them... that's a lot.

Comment: You might need multiple updates.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Cool, multiple updates solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bpy.context.view_layer.update()` should do it.

See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#stale-data

Comment: It works successfully with a 80% chance. Sometimes you have to click on the script button twice to update everything.

Comment: @ugorek, could you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Python script changes rotations of an object (light). The driver for rotating an object along the z axis changes the sun rotation of the "Sky Texture" node in "World". The code `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` 
successfully updates the driver at 80% chance when the Run button is clicked.

Comment: Could you maybe share the code? You could edit the question and include it there.